# Desktop tag must go!

Tags: discussion, tags

[desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/desktop) is something we all use, unless you want to specifically refer to [server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/server) (as in, I dont have a desktop, this is a server) most questions will be directly related to it.

That renders the tag useless to anyone following it. It, by usage, proves to be useless to exist. Still many users use it to describe the most awesome issues with their systems and it proves hard to keep track and clean all the posts in the site that use it.

I want the community to think about and let us know your opinion on blacklisting permanently the tag.

Do you think it is useful, or do you find any need to keep it around? Or can we blacklist this so we have no more need to keep on cleaning it?

Comment: I vote for blacklisting it.

Comment: From orbit ... it's the only way to be sure.

Comment: It's only 365 questions... :)

Comment: It looks like the desktop tag got recreated a couple of days ago.

Comment: @maggotbrain it was not blacklisted, only cleaned. If you see it, edit the posts and remove it! :) thx

Answer (score 11):

I could kinda see this working specifically for questions on "desktop environments" - but obviously those are the minority.

[image: burninated]

I've removed the tag - if it re-appears, we can blacklist it.

Comment: We've got [tag:desktop-environments] already, which seems to cover that.

Comment: It has reappeared. [tag:desktop]

Comment: And now it's blacklisted, @Seth.

Comment: Thank you very much @Shog9!

Answer (score 6):

### Let's Do It.

```
echo desktop|sudo tee -a /etc/stackexchange/askubuntu/config/tags/blacklist
```

It appears that it is too meta and adds not much information, if at all any, to the question. There should be no harm in blacklisting it.

Comment: Thanks @ObsessiveFOSS! Thats reasonable.

Comment: Geeky answer :p

Comment: `sudo echo >>` is unlikely to do what you want it to do. ;)

Comment: Ah that, yes. the echo runs as `root` but the redirection is done by bash, which simply complains `Error: you need supercow powers to do that.`